# Difference between flatMap, flatTap, evalMap and evalTap

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

In Scala fs2 library for functional streams:

I am trying to understand the difference between `flatMap`, `flatTap`, `evalMap` and `evalTap`. They all seem to perform the same thing, which is transformation of the stream values.

What is the difference and when each of them should be used?

Comment: You might find useful [Cats github examples](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/FlatMap.scala) to understand general idea how flatTap differs from flatMap :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Traditionally, `tap` like functions allow you to observe (or peek into) the elements in the stream, but discard the result of the observing effect. For example, in fs2 you can see the signature for `evalTap` is:

```
def evalTap[F2[x] >: F[x]](f: (O) ⇒ F2[_])(implicit arg0: Functor[F2]): Stream[F2, O]
```

Notice how `f` is a function from `O => F2[_]`, meaning "you take an `O` value and return an effect type `F2` for which a Functor exists", but it doesn't affect the return type of the stream, which is still `O`.

For example, in case we want to emit elements of the stream to the console, we can do:

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import cats.implicits._

object Test extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    fs2
      .Stream(1, 2, 3)
      .covary[IO]
      .evalTap(i => IO(println(i)))
      .map(_ + 1)
      .compile
      .drain
      .as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

This will yield `1 2 3`.

You can see that we emit each element of the stream to the console using `evalTap`, where we have an effect of type `IO[Unit]`, yet we can immediately `map` each such element in the next step of the pipeline as it didn't effect to result type of the stream.

I couldn't find `flatTap` but I think they're generally the same in fs2 (https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/issues/1177)

On the other hand, a function like `flatMap` does cause the return type of the stream to change. We can see the signature:

```
def flatMap[F2[x] >: F[x], O2](f: O => Stream[F2, O2]): Stream[F2, O2] =
```

Notice how unlike `evalTap`, the result of executing `f` is `O2`, which is also encoded in the return type. If we take the same example as above:

```
fs2
  .Stream(1, 2, 3)
  .covary[IO]
  .flatMap(i => fs2.Stream(IO(println(i))))
  .map(_ + 1)
  .compile
  .drain
  .as(ExitCode.Success)
```

This will no longer compile, as `flatMap` returns an `Stream[IO, Unit]`, meaning that the execution of `println` and the fact that it returns `Unit` directly affects downstream combinators.

`evalMap` is an alias for a `flatMap` which allows you to omit the wrapping of the `Stream` type and is generally implemented in terms of `flatMap`:

```
def evalMap[F2[x] >: F[x], O2](f: O => F2[O2]): Stream[F2, O2] =
  flatMap(o => Stream.eval(f(o)))
```

Which is a bit more convenient to use.